# Zebra LP2824 prints only half of the label

Tags: windows-xp, label-printer

I have Zebra LP 2824 printer. I don't have the serial number, but I found out that it used to be from UPS to print labels. From the store Zebra told me that I can use it to print labels for jewellery. Is there any way that we can fix that problem because is only printing half of the label?

Comment: What driver ZPL, EPL, ZUD? I'm pretty sure I know exactly whats wrong here I just need to know which version of the driver you are using.  Oh yeah, congratulations on buying one the most frustrating brand of printers on the market... I have been through hell with these damn things and we have close to 50 of them, hopefully I can help ease the frustration...

Answer (score 1):

Well since I am leaving for the day I will leave you with a quick walk through on how to change the label size. Right click the printer, click properties, and go into printing preferences in the general tab. Next choose your label size:

[image]

While you are in there you might want to go to media settings and change the darkness, I have found through trial and error that 22 darkness looks very nice. You will also have to do the exact same thing you just did here, in printing defaults under the advanced tab (pictured below). The layout after getting in there is exactly the same as printing preferences:

[image]

Now keep in mind it is entirely possible that it will still continue to print with the old settings, sometimes this works sometimes it doesn't. Zebra support is unable to explain to me why this happens (even on brand new printers). Anyway if this happens to you a firmware update will be necessary. You can get the new firmware and the flash utility [here](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/drivers_downloads.html). You will have to create an account to download it but it shouldn't take too long and they don't ask any specifics about your printer (if I remember correctly).

EDIT: The steps I outlined above are for standard single labels if you have double labels or specialty labels it may differ slightly. Just let me know what your setup is if you don't use standard single labels.

Answer (score 1):

On my LP 2824 Plus I fixed the problem by going to Printing Preferences, Tools, Calibrate Media and it worked again!